# Convert blob from csv, imported as string

Tags: python, csv, import, runtime-error, blob

I am trying to read Blob-Data which is stored in a csv-file. I can import it in string format but if I want to use numpy.frombuffer with dtype='<f4' (fixed to get correct output), I get the error:

```
line 52, in <module>
data = np.frombuffer(blob_data, dtype='<f4') #<f4
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size
```

The code is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math
import csv
import pandas
from binascii import unhexlify
#import mysql.connector
# from pylab import figure, plot, show, legend, xlabel, ylabel
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def read_CSV(dataid):
    with open('spectrometer2.csv') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            line_count = 0
            result = bytes('1',encoding='UTF-8')
            for row in csv_reader:
                if line_count > 0:
                    #print(row[0])
                    if str(dataid) == str(row[0]):
                        result = row[3][2:-1]
                        print('FOUND####################################')
                        print(str(row[3])[2:-1])
                        break
                line_count += 1
            print(str(type(result)))
            return result


####### MAIN PROGRAM #######

#spectrumRange = np.arange(10, 11011, 200)
spectrumRange = np.arange(8000, 9000, 200) # Auszug zur Leistungsoptimierung im Test

query_init = "SELECT * FROM `spectrometer2` WHERE data_id="

plt.figure()

for spectrum_id in spectrumRange:
    spectrometerquery = query_init + str(spectrum_id) + ";"
    print("Current data ID: " + str(spectrum_id))
    #y_stream = interact_with_MySQL("database_name", spectrometerquery)

    blob_data = read_CSV(spectrum_id)
    #print(binary2int(blob_data))    
    if(blob_data != 0):

        blob_data = bytes(blob_data,encoding = 'UTF-8')
        
        print(blob_data)
        data = np.frombuffer(blob_data, dtype='<f4') #<f4

        print(data)
        plt.plot(data)

plt.title('Spectrometer 2 data')

legend = []
for x in spectrumRange:
    legend.append(('data id:', x))

plt.legend(legend)
plt.show()
```

I don't know much about the csv-file but it should contain the output of a optical sensor. The sql-statements are commented out because I have to replace them with the csv-file.

Extract of the file (shown in excel):
[image: extract of the file]

Comment: The code block where you show the error doesn't actually show an exception, only the location, could you include this part? Also, that file extract didn't look like a csv file, is that definitely the type you are looking for or did you just put it in a spreadsheet?

Comment: @CmdCoder858 shure, sorry:
line 52, in <module>
    data = np.frombuffer(blob_data, dtype='<f4') #<f4
ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

It is a csv-file but opened in excel

Comment: I haven't been able to find much on the buffer encodings but I think the most likely causes are corrupted data or an invalid data type. I would suggest making sure the data is intact and possibly experimenting with different dtypes other than '<f4'. Other than that I can't think of another explaination.

Comment: @CmdCoder858 The data is intact. I tried it with binary 'b' but then the integers are way too small. The difficulty is if i use the output from read_CSV it looks like b'\xfb\xc3a?\ but i cant use it in the np.frombuffer function. if i convert it via bytes() it looks like b'b'\\xfb\\... so every \ is doubled. But I have no idea how to tell python that the output of read_CSV is type bytes and NOT string. You know what I mean?

Comment: If the function expects a string then maybe that is what you should give it. You're converting the blob_data to bytes. Might it work if you leave it as a string perhaps?

Comment: @CmdCoder858 leaving it as a string causes the error: "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" is there a possibility to declare the read string as bytes/blob without converting?

Comment: I'm really not sure what else you could try at this point. The only things I could suggest is dig through then numpy docs to find a solution or just try something else because I am completely at a loss.